# Detect call state change in VOIP Android apps

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, skype, google-hangouts

Is there a way to detect the beginning/ending of voice calls in apps such as Google Hangouts / Skype? (I know this is a shot in the dark, but I was wondering if anyone researched this option).

I'm interested in something like Android's receivers for the android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE and the android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL actions

Comment: Did you get any proper solution?

Answer (score 1):

Skype broadcast:

```
com.skype.android.CONVERSATION_LIVE_STATE
```

There u can read:

```
com.skype.live_identity -> ur friend
com.skype.live_status -> RINGING_FOR_ME or STARTING or NONE
com.skype.account -> your account
```

Comment: Its not working for me. Can you please elaborate this answer. How can I use it?